# Python - Averaging items in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like so

```
[[name1, 10.10], [name2, 12.12], [name1, 9.90], [name3, 22.20], [name3, 7.70]]
```

I want to search through the bigger list for the individual lists with the same first element, then average the second element, then append the new average value to a new list like so:

```
[[name1, 10.00], [name2, 12.12], [name3, 14.95]]
```

The problem is I don't know how to search through the lists to do so. I'm very new to python, can someone help?

Comment: Why were three elements removed?

Comment: You want to have each name appear only once in your final list, correct? if so, you do not want to use a list for your final structure, you want a dictionary.

Comment: Your last score is `7,70` or `7.70`?

Comment: Isn't this names strings?

Comment: Edit: I'll just submit an answer, formatting in comments sucks.

Comment: Do you need to retain the order of `name1`, `name2`, and so on as they appear in the original list?

Comment: I can sort them into the correct order later on in the program, I do however need the final info in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store every name with corresponding values :

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> l=[['name1', 10.1], ['name2', 12.12], ['name1', 9.9], ['name3', 22.2], ['name3', 7.70]]
>>> d={}
>>> for i in l:
...     d.setdefault(i[0],[]).extend(i[1:])
... 
>>> d
{'name2': [12.12], 'name3': [22.2, 7.7], 'name1': [10.1, 9.9]}
>>> [[i,sum(j)/len(j)] for i,j in d.items()]
[['name2', 12.12], ['name3', 14.95], ['name1', 10.0]]
```

`Note` that this answer works if you have more that 1 number in your sub lists!!

But for this case as i write before edit you can just do :

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> l=[['name1', 10.1], ['name2', 12.12], ['name1', 9.9], ['name3', 22.2], ['name3', 7.70]]
>>> d={}
>>> for i,j in l:
...     d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
... 
>>> d
{'name2': [12.12], 'name3': [22.2, 7.7], 'name1': [10.1, 9.9]}
>>> [[i,sum(j)/len(j)] for i,j in d.items()]
[['name2', 12.12], ['name3', 14.95], ['name1', 10.0]]
```

Comment: The average for `name3` is not 17.3666.

Comment: @zachgates7 i thought that its a typo by OP, thanks for reminding , fixed!

Comment: It isn't `33.066` either; notice how in the question the average is `14.95`. The `7,70` in the question is a typo.

Comment: @zachgates7 yeah i got it, the problem is because of `division`, fixed!

Comment: **Down voters pls attention to the edit! and remove your down votes!**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function to loop over the items:

```
def averageItems(items):
    averages = {}
    for name, data in items:
        averages.setdefault(name, []).append(data)
    for name, data in averages.items():
        averages[name] = sum(data) / len(data)
    return averages
```

Then use your list:

```
data = [[name1, 10.10], [name2, 12.12], [name1, 9.90], [name3, 22.20], [name3, 7.70]]
dataAverages = averageItems(data) # {name3: 14.95, name2: 12.12, name1: 10.0}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't works. You forgot to quote strings.

Comment: I edited the question according to the post. The post does not have quotations, indicating that they are variables. @MauroBaraldi

Comment: But you paste the example as you have ran in shell. Certainly it did not work as you paste.

Comment: There is no need for .keys

Comment: Thank you. Defining functions isn't a strong point for me yet, but I think I can follow your example in constructing my own

Comment: Thank you, I've added your suggestion. @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a dictionary whose values are lists of numbers, using the [`.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method of dictionaries.
2. Build a list using the builtins [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) to compute the mean.

Using the [`ipython`](http://ipython.org) interpreter

```
In [1]: l = [['name1', 10.10], ['name2', 12.12], ['name1', 9.90], ['name3', 22.20], ['name3', 7.70]]
In [2]: d = {}
In [3]: for k, v in l: d[k]=d.setdefault(k,[])+[v]
In [4]: [[k,sum(d[k])/len(d[k])] for k in d]
Out[4]: [['name2', 12.12], ['name3', 14.95], ['name1', 10.0]]
In [5]: del d
In [6]:
```

---

Prompted by [Kevin's comment to the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480288/python-averaging-items-in-a-list-of-lists#comment47122058_29480288) about the eventual requirement of conserving the order  of  labels in the original list, I'd suggest using an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module

```
In [19]: from collections import OrderedDict
In [20]: d = OrderedDict()
In [21]: for k, v in l: d[k]=d.setdefault(k,[])+[v]
In [22]: [[k,sum(d[k])/len(d[k])] for k in d]
Out[22]: [['name1', 10.0], ['name2', 12.12], ['name3', 14.95]]
```

Comment: So whats the difference with my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to store all the scores for each name in a single list and  then use [statistics.mean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) if you have python >= 3.4 to calculate the average:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

l = [['name1', 10.10], ['name2', 12.12], ['name1', 9.90], ['name3', 22.20], ['name3', 7.70]]


details = defaultdict(list)

for name, score in l:
    details[name].append(score)
```

If you want to keep the dict structure just update the values:

```
for name, scores in details.items():
    details[name] = mean(scores)

print(details)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'name3': 14.95, 'name1': 10.0, 'name2': 12.12})
```

Or create a list using a list comprehension:

```
print([[name ,mean(scores)] for name,scores in details.items()])
[['name1', 10.0], ['name3', 14.95], ['name2', 12.12]]
```

Obviously without using mean you can simple calcualte it yourself:

```
print([[name , sum(scores)/len(scores)] for name,scores in details.items()])
```

If the order matters then use a [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
details = OrderedDict()

for name, score in l:
    details.setdefault(name,[])
    details[name].append(score)

print([[name , sum(scores)/len(scores)] for name,scores in details.items()])
```

Comment: Using `mean` is great if you've over 3.x. If not, you'll have to sum and divide manually (the horror~)

Comment: @ap. I  have already stated that you need python 3.4 or greater. This actually works and gives the correct result, I am sure the OP can figure out how to average without using mean.

Comment: You're right, I just missed it at first (didn't read your preamble). Wasn't bashing, just pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import add

d = defaultdict(list)
pairs = [[name1, 10.10], [name2, 12.12], [name1, 9.90], [name3, 22.20], [name3, 7.70]]

for name, val in pairs: 
    d[name].append(val)
print [(name, reduce(add, vals)/len(vals)) for name, vals in d.items()]
```

I think this should work, and it's fairly clean too. We create a defaultdict and append each value for each name to a list, then reduce those down by adding, and then divide by length to get an average.

Comment: Your last line should be `print([[name, reduce(add, vals)/len(vals)] for name, vals in d.items()])`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `.items()` part.